# Let $ a \in (0,1) $ and S = $ \{a^{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Then $ \inf S = 0$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I was proving the statement, 'Let $ a \in (0,1) $ and S = $ \{a^{n}\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Then $ \inf S = 0$'

In that process, I need to prove other statement, but I couldn't. It is following one.

**Given a number $\varepsilon \gt 0 $, there exists a natural number $n$ such that $a^{n} \lt \varepsilon $.**

To prove it, I divided by the case,
(i) $\varepsilon \ge 1 $ (ii) $ a \lt \varepsilon \lt 1 $ (iii) $\varepsilon = a $ (iv) $ 0 \lt \varepsilon \lt a $
However, I can't prove the case (iv)

If someone knows how or other way to prove it, please help me.
Thank you.

Comment: You can prove $(a^n)_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ is decreasing and bounded below and thus converges to $\inf_{n \geq 1}a^n$. Then you note that $$\lim(a^n) = \lim(a^{n + 1}) = a \lim(a^n)$$

Comment: @Mason Thank you for your tip, but this problem is before than 'monotone convergence theorem'. Anyway very thank you!!

Comment: The monotone convergence theorem is simple to prove. Namely for any $\varepsilon > 0$, there exists an $n \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 1$ such that
$$\inf_{n \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 1}a^n \leq a^n < \inf_{n \in \mathbb{Z} \geq 1}a^n + \varepsilon.$$

Comment: @Mason Wow I really appreciate your kindness :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an elementary argument: By the Bernoulli inequality we have $$\frac{1}{a^n}=(1+(\frac{1}{a}-1))^n\geq1+n(\frac{1}{a}-1)\geq n(\frac{1}{a}-1)$$
Therefore: $$a^n\leq K\frac{1}{n}$$
with $K=\frac{a}{1-a}>0$. By the Archimedian property there is some $n\in \Bbb N$ with $$\frac{K}{\varepsilon}<n$$
Can you finish from here?

Comment: Thank you for your help :) Have a nice day!!